# \includegraphics[width=40mm], reserves correct space, but includes full size image

Tags: graphics, scaling, png, resolution

I'm using the following code to include an image. The reserved space in the resulting .pdf document is correct and changes according to the width I set. Nevertheless, the .png is always embedded in full size and doesn't change with the width parameter. I read in other posts, that maybe the .png is missing resolution information. But I changed the resolution with Photoshop and had no success either. I also added the `resolution` parameter to `\includegraphics`, with no luck.

```
\begin{figure}[bbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[resolution=72, width=40mm]{bilder/rmv_tag.png}
\caption[RMV-Kontaktpunkt am Bahnhof]{RMV-Kontaktpunkt am Bahnhof, Quelle:
http://goo.gl/i1k0l}
\label{pic:rmv}
\end{figure}
```

I'm using the graphicx-package and pdflatex on my mac.

---

Update: This is my image:
[image]

Comment: Can you upload the file (without incurring in copyright infringements)?

Comment: I just did. See above.

Comment: Stupid me. I used a complete style from someone else, even though I've gone through all `\userpackage`, I must have overseen the following: \usepackage{layouts}[2001/04/29] \makeindex I don't see, why this statement messed up my image, but well, now it works. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5):

In the log file are you getting a message saying that TeX cannot find the bounding box
size of the `.png` file? If so then you will have to supply the bounding box dimensions by measuring them in some graphics editor and then use the following `\includegraphics` command:

```
\includegraphics[bb=0 0 urx ury, width=40mm]{yourGraphicsFile.png}
```

where `urx`, `ury` are the x,y coordinates of the upper right corner in (big) points

Comment: There is no bounding box message in the log. I just tried it anyways with the 'bb' parameter, but it didn't work either.